# Ploting graph from data while missing one row (R language)

Tags: r, plot, graph, charts

I have data saved in table:

```
num     count
-------------
  1       123 
  2        67 
  3        98 
  4        80 
  6       135
```

Is there any way how to plot it in R such that values on X-axis are {1,2,3,4,5,6}? There is missing value 5 in 'num' column but I want to include it in graph with count=0.

Comment: `Table = rbind(Table, c(5,0))`  ?

Comment: And if I don't know that num=5 will be missing? I want to do that for every row from i=1 to 100. Just in case that i is not included in 'num' column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will use your sample data,but only go up to 10, so that it is easy to print the results.

```
## Your data
Table1 = read.table(text="num     count
  1       123 
  2        67 
  3        98 
  4        80 
  6       135 ",
header=TRUE)


Table2 = data.frame(num = 1:10, count=0)
Table2$count[Table1$num] = Table1$count
Table2
   num count
1    1   123
2    2    67
3    3    98
4    4    80
5    5     0
6    6   135
7    7     0
8    8     0
9    9     0
10  10     0
```